# Issue when building react-native app vie expo

Tags: react-native, build, expo, apk, eas

I try to build react-native expo project..
!!! WORKING PERFECTLY ON SIMULATORS BOTH ANDROID AND IOS BUT NOT ON REAL DEVICE !!!

1.with eas build: -- when I download the builded .apk on a real device doesn't want to fetch any information I have error handling with alert ! And only the alert is showing

2.With expo build:android .. builds 20 minutes it says the build fails but still produce downloadable .apk when I download it on a real device now fetching works and we come to the point where the user must press a button and give permission to location to navigate to other screen where is map with directions from Google Directions API, but when you press the button and give permission its like the app freezes and won't navigate to the other screen...

ANY IDEAS ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands your question is very hard to answer, since there aren't any code or error messages. Please see [ask] and how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your text is pretty hard to read because it lacks punctuation marks and thus sentences.